# Attachement's name encoding fails

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, mime-types, mime

I try to send an email with an attachment (A pdf file), but the receiver receives a file with a different name and without the .pdf ending. The name of the file is in Greek..

```
try {
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("from@mail.com"));
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(mail));
    message.setSubject(title,"utf-8");

    // Create the message part
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

    // Now set the actual message
    messageBodyPart.setText("This is message body");

    // Create a multipar message
    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

    // Set text message part
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

    // Part two is attachment
    messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

    String filename = "file.pdf";
    String f = name + " Πρόγραμμα Ιανουάριος 2016.pdf";  // the desired name of the file
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(MimeUtility.encodeText(f, "UTF-8", null));
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

    // Send the complete message parts
    message.setContent(multipart);

    Transport.send(message);

    System.out.println("Mail " + mail +" sent");
} catch (MessagingException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

the `name` is a string variable and is getting a value previously. The strange is that if I have `String f = name + " αααα.pdf"` the receiver is getting a pdf succesfully with the name `Ρουβάς αααα.pdf` but if i have this String `f = name + " Πρόγραμμα Ιανουάριος 2016.pdf";` he doesn't. He is getting sth like 
`=_UTF-8_B_zpzOtc Dz4POsc67zrHPgiDOmc6xzr3Ov8 FzqzPgc65zr_Pgi___ ___filename_1=__5wZGY=_=`

I added the `message.writeTo(System.out);` and I got:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; 
    bou

    ndary="----=_Part_0_1825884453.1457025565509"

    ------=_Part_0_1825884453.1457025565509
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

    This is message body
    ------=_Part_0_1825884453.1457025565509
    Content-Type: application/octet-stream; 
        name*0="=?UTF-8?B?zpzOtc+Dz4POsc67zrHPgiDOmc6xzr3Ov8+FzrHPgc6vzr/Pgi"; 
        name*1="Ay?=
     =?UTF-8?B?MDE2zpnOsc69zr/Phc6sz4HOuc6/z4IgMjAxNi5wZGY=?"; 
        name*2="="
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
    Content-Disposition: attachment; 
        filename*0="=?UTF-8?B?zpzOtc+Dz4POsc67zrHPgiDOmc6xzr3Ov8+FzrHPgc6vzr/Pgi"; 
        filename*1="Ay?=
     =?UTF-8?B?MDE2zpnOsc69zr/Phc6sz4HOuc6/z4IgMjAxNi5wZGY=?"; 
        filename*2="="
```

with `props.setProperty("mail.mime.encodeparameters", "false");` or `true`

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; 
    boundary="----=_Part_0_797681969.1457074816557"

------=_Part_0_797681969.1457074816557
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

This is message body
------=_Part_0_797681969.1457074816557
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="?????????? 2016.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; 
    filename*=Cp1252''%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%202016.pdf
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to encode the filename explicitly; JavaMail should do that for you when you call setFileName.  What version of JavaMail are you using?  If you add `message.writeTo(System.out);` before the Transport.send, what do the message headers look like?  What program is being used to read and display the received message?

Comment: I use `JavaMail is 1.5.5.` The file that the receiver gets has no file ending, so if you add the .pdf you will open it normally.

Comment: I added the output of the `message.writeTo(System.out);` to the question @BillShannon

Comment: if you have the instance of MimeMessageHelper, you may add 'mimeMessageHelper.setEncodeFilenames(false)' and it will help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you're encoding the filename yourself, you're using the non-standard MIME encoding format, as described in the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#encodefilename).  That non-standard encoded text is then being split into multiple parameters using the standard RFC 2231 technique.  It's this mix of non-standard and standard format that's probably causing the confusion for the mail reader.

Try letting JavaMail do the encoding for you by removing the call to `MimeUtility.encodeText`.  If that doesn't work, set the System property `mail.mime.encodeparameters` to `false` to disable the RFC 2231 encoding.

Comment: I removed the `MimeUtility.encodeText` and I had an improvement as I recceive a pdf file, but with name `????? ???? ???? ???.pdf` . Then I added: `props.setProperty("mail.mime.encodeparameters", "false");` and with `true` but I get also the ????????.pdf

Comment: I added to the question the result of `message.writeTo(System.out);`

Comment: It looks like your default charset is not appropriate for the characters in the file name.  Try setting the System property `mail.mime.charset` to "utf-8".

Comment: @yaylitzis The property `mail.mime.encodeparameters`  is a system property, so you should instead write `System.setProperty("mail.mime.encodeparameters",  "false");`

Comment: Hi @BillShannon I am facing the same issue but in decoding. My input file has filename*0="Post Discharge Follow-Up Call Script doc$454c0369-1283-4446-a07d"; filename*1=-cdc4cb175da8.pdf in payload, and when I do below parsing, it removed filename*1 in parsed object. Can you please suggest workaround. This is what I am parsing. MimeMessage message=new MimeMessage(IncomingMessage.getMessage()); MimeMessageParser parser = new MimeMessageParser(message); parser.parse(); When I do this, and try to get attachment -> getfilename, it gives blank file name.