# Encoding attachment using javax.mail fails

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, mime-types, mime

We have an application wherein we can attach a file and send it via email. We are using `javax.mail` for this and it was working fine earlier. Before attaching the file, we encode the file name as below:

```
attachmentName = MimeUtility.encodeWord(attachmentName, "UTF-8", null);
```

Earlier we were using javax,mail version 1.4. Recently we moved to version 1.6.2
Now for some non-english file names, we are getting garbage values such as `UTF-8_Q=E8=A1=A8=5FSUSAR=E7=A0=94=E7=A9=B6=E4=B8=AD`

From this FAQ https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#encodefilename I got to know that for latest `javax.mail` versions, we should not manually encode the file name again and so, I removed the above line from code, but now, I am getting file name with all question marks in the attachment.

My issue is similar to the one mentioned here:
[Attachement's name encoding fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35673240/attachements-name-encoding-fails)

I tried setting this property to false but no luck:

```
System.setProperty("mail.mime.encodeparameters",  "false");
```

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: Could you please help for this issue?@bill-shannon

Comment: You should show full of mail sending source code.